# Почему в словах которые из function.php пропадают немецкие буквы? как поправить?

Tags: php, wordpress

вывелось вместо букв знаки вопроса фаил в win1251
Teilen Sie uns bitte Ihre Telefonnummer mit. Ihre Telefonnummer ben?tigen wir nur f?r den sicheren Versand der Ware.

```
if(get_locale() == "de_DE"){
        $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['label'] = apply_filters( 'woocommerce', __( 'Company phone.', 'woocommerce' ) )." ". "<span class='phone-text'>Teilen Sie uns bitte Ihre Telefonnummer mit.
Ihre Telefonnummer benötigen wir nur für den sicheren Versand der Ware.</span>" ;}
```

Comment: Потому что [win1251](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251). Куда боле интересный вопрос - откуда взялся win1251  в ВП.

Comment: @SeVlad Потому что с локалки льют на сервер не глядя)

Comment: @KAGGDesign ну оно б и на локалке было б тоже самое (а ежели нет системного немецкого, то и ещё веселее). Но вообще я как бэ намекнул что в ВП 1251 в принципе быть не должно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если коротко, то кодировка win1251 самую малость кириллическая, в ней нет умляутов и прочих немецких букв. Вам намекают в комментах, что в Вордпрессе изначально установлена кодировка UTF-8.

Приведите весь код на сайте к этой кодировке и будет вам счастье.